# Create float range with Aforge

Tags: c#, aforge

I tried to create a float range using the Aforge library, but the problem is that Range is undefined. I tried the following:

```
Range range1 = new Range( 0.25f, 1.5f );
```

Should I define Range as a public func?

Comment: It sounds like you're probably missing an assembly reference or a `using` directive. A short but complete console app demonstrating the problem would make your question clearer. Assuming `Range` is meant to be a type in the library (it would help if you linked to the relevant docs) you shouldn't need to declare it yourself at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (found [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/docs/html/d11074ed-1fb4-ea04-dc13-ae80bb105699.htm)), your code should work. Make sure you have referenced the .DLL in your project and that you have an appropriate `using` directive in your code file (or use the fully qualified name).